# Mongoose Model alias error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, alias

I have a funny issue with Mongoose, one of MongoDB's ODMs.

I wanted to alias the `mongoose.model` method into simply `Model`. I even checked the alias :

```
exports = Model = mongoose.model;
console.log(Model === mongoose.model); // returns true
```

I already did this for `mongoose.Schema` and it worked seamlessly.

Now when I register a schema using the aliased `Model` variable :

```
Model('User', UserSchema);
```

I get the following error :

```
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:257
  if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) {
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined
    at Mongoose.model (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:257:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/user.js:20:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at controllers_path (/app.js:23:2)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

But if I use the normal form, I get absolutely no errors :

```
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

- Is this a bug in the `Mongoose.js ODM` or am I missing something ?

Comment: `Model` is the constructor function for Model objects; it seems at best very confusing to change that locally to be the `mongoose.model` function.  Did you try using an alias of `model` instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Even with random names, it doesn't work and returns the same error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you call `mongoose.model(...)`, the `mongoose` object is getting passed into the `model` function as `this`.  When you call the function through your alias, `this` will be set to `global` instead of `mongoose`.

If you really wanted to do this you'd have to do something like:

```
var Model = mongoose.model.bind(mongoose);
```

That way, `mongoose` gets passed into the function no matter how you call `Model`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on @JohnnyHK answer:

```
var a = {
    b:function(){
        console.log(this.name)
    },
    name:"its a"
}
a.b() //logs "its a"
var c = a.b;
c(); //logs undefined
```

While calling `c` the invoking context is window or the global object.